# python openpyxl font (unexpected keyword argument size)

Tags: python, fonts, openpyxl

My code is as follows

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Style
bold16font = Font(size=16, bold=True)
```

I keep getting the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "G:\Create WBv2.py", line
>   24, in 
>       bold16font = Font(size=16, bold=True) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bold'

I've looked this up and even coppied directly from the [toturial](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) and keep getting this error. Whats going on here?

Comment: That code works for me.  What does `print(openpyxl.__version__)` return?

Comment: That's quite old; the current version is ~2.2.4 or so.  Try updating.

Comment: I think its working now. updated using "conda update openpyxl"

Answer (score -2):

Update your package. command line:  pip install openpyxl --upgrade